# App.js not rendering in Expo (React Native)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am getting a render error when trying to view App.js in react native using Expo. I'm not sure what is wrong...

Error is "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

This occurred when i added NavigationContainer and AuthNavigator.

```
    import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar, NavigationContainer } from "react-native";


import AuthNavigator from "./app/navigation/AuthNavigator";

const BAR_HEIGHT = StatusBar.currentHeight;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  statusColor: {
    backgroundColor: "#000",
  },
  viewController: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewController}>
    <StatusBar style={styles.statusColor} />
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems You forgot to import `NavigationContainer`  correctly.

You are supposed to import it from `@react-navigation/native` and not from `react-native`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar} from "react-native";
//-----------
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import AuthNavigator from "./app/navigation/AuthNavigator";

const BAR_HEIGHT = StatusBar.currentHeight;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  statusColor: {
    backgroundColor: "#000",
  },
  viewController: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewController}>
    <StatusBar style={styles.statusColor} />
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
    
  );
}
```